# Is it possible to use EasyMock/JMock for AWS Java SDKs mocking & code coverage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, easymock

I am using AWS Java SDKs to connect to multiple AWS services such as DynamoDB, API-Gateway,EC2,GlueJob,CloudWatch,SQS,S3 and etc.

Question: Is it possible to use EasyMock/JMock for AWS Java SDKs mocking & code coverage?

NOTE: I know about Serverless mocking framweworks such as LocalStack, DynamoDbLocal, SAM CLI, DynamoDbLocal but i would like to know whether mocking can be completely achieved using EasyMock/JMock java libs???

Any one tried to mock AWS services using EasyMock/JMock?

Thanks,
Sundar

Comment: At least AWS Java SDK developers tried to mock AWS services with EasyMock. See test dependencies here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.11.44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You just need to mock the service you are calling and return whatever answer is wanted by your test.

However, I would recommend to wrap AWS calls in a class that will be itself mock by everybody else. Because AWS is not that fun to mock. The objects returned by services are fairly complicated in general.

So isolate AWS in a class and then only mock AWS to test this class. Try to retrieve real calls to correctly mimic the answers from services.